# jQuery get .text and use as class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the text content from a div and add it as an extra class, I have managed to figure out how to get it, but I can't understand how to make lowercase and remove spaces so it acts as a good class.

What I have so far;

```
    <div class="main-amen-text">Apple</div>
    <div class="main-amen-text">Something Fruity</div>

    $.each($('.main-amen-text'), function () {
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).addClass('main-amen-text-' + text);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
text.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
```

Comment: Thanks, Just got it         $.each($('.main-amen-text'), function () {
    var text = $(this).html().replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    $(this).addClass('main-amen-text-' + text);
});

Comment: Accept the Answer if its Helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($('.main-amen-text'), function() {
    var text = $(this).html().replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    $(this).addClass('main-amen-text-' + text);
});
```